# How to iterate an ArrayList of HashMap

Tags: arraylist, hashmap, iterator

I have an arraylist of hashmap.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

I want to iterate that one.I am doing like this.

```
       Iterator it=al.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){

           it.remove(); 
                }
```

but i want to compare like this before remove.but its not working.how i can get value from al?

if(al.get(it).get(db.name).equalsIgnoreCase(var)){

```
                         it.remove();       
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a value from the iterator, use `it.next()` instead of `al.get(it)`

```
HashMap<String, String> map = it.next();
if (map.get(db.name).equalsIgnoreCase(var)) {
    it.remove();       
}
```